# Two way data binding between a component and a directive on the same element?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular-components

```
<tab mousePosCollector></tab>
```

The `MousePosCollectorDirective` and `TabComponent` both have a property `x`. How can property `x` be updated in the `TabComponent` when property `x` changes in the `MousePosCollectorDirective`?

Standard two way data binding does not seem to be a solution for my case.

```
<tab mousePosCollector [(x)]="x"></tab>
```

This would initiate a two way data binding between the `MousePosCollectorDirective` and the parent component of `TabComponent`, not `TabComponent` itself, which is what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess two-way binding should work **[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/zR2k5Qi9YqlZmL04wzaK?p=preview)**:

**directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[mousePosCollector]'
})
export class MousePosCollectorDirective  {
  @Input() x;
  @Output() xChange = new EventEmitter();
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.x = ++this.x;
      this.xChange.emit(this.x);
    }, 1000)
  }
  ngOnChanges() {
    console.info(`Changes from MousePosCollectorDirective: ${this.x}`);
  }
}
```

**component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tab',
  template: `<h3>tab {{x}}</h3>`
})
export class TabComponent {
  @Input() x;
  @Output() xChange = new EventEmitter();
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.x = ++this.x;
      this.xChange.emit(this.x);
    }, 2000)
  }
  ngOnChanges() {
    console.info(`Changes from TabComponent: ${this.x}`);
  }
}
```

**parent component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <tab mousePosCollector [(x)]="x"></tab>
    {{x}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
  x = 1;
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.x = ++this.x;
    }, 3000)
  }
}
```